# Android Circular Image View not centering image

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-image

I'm using [Circular Image View](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) in order to display some Pokemon inside:

[image]

All the images are 300x300 and they doesn't fit in the circular image view.

These image views are created programmatically and added in a Linear Layout:

```
    PokemonTeam pokemonTeam = mData.get(position);

    for (Pokemon pokemon : pokemonTeam.getPokemonList()) {
        CircularImageView ivPokemonSprite = new CircularImageView(mContext);
        int color = PokemonUtils.getDominantColorFromPokemon(pokemon.get_id(), mContext);
        ivPokemonSprite.setBorderColor(color);
        ivPokemonSprite.setBorderWidth(4);
         ivPokemonSprite.setCircleColor( PokemonUtils.lighterColor(color, DARK_FACTOR));
        ivPokemonSprite.setShadowEnable(true);
        ivPokemonSprite.setShadowRadius(10);
        Picasso.get().load(PokemonUtils.getPokemonSugimoriImageById(pokemon.get_id(), mContext)).fit().centerCrop().into(ivPokemonSprite);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 200, 1f);
        ivPokemonSprite.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        holder.teamSpritesLinearLayout.addView(ivPokemonSprite);
    }
```

I dont know exactly how to center the image of the Pokemon inside the Circular Image View I've tried changing CENTER_CROP to FIT_CENTER or CENTER but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

note that you are using `.fit().centerCrop()` method in Picasso line - your image is bigger that `View` so Picasso will download and cut it, then set to `ImageView`. `scaleType` set for `ImageView` doesn't matter in here as Picasso will provide image with exacly same size as `ImageView` so any scaling won't happen, not needed

try with `.fit().centerInside()` - this should force Picasso to download and set image as-is (without cutting) and centering inside should work

Comment: please check with fixed width & height (e.g. 200 for both, but should use `dp`) and also try to run Picasso after setting `LayoutParams`. maybe this tool is trying to get size of `View` at first and then starts networking, croping and setting downloeaded `Bitmap`